# Is there any way to update customData/user data on a virtual machine in Azure

Tags: azure

CustomData can be injected to a virtual machine at the time of cloning. I am looking for a way to inject/update the custom data on existing VM.

I am using Java SDK for Azure, and in VirtualMachine.update I couldn't figure out a method to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating or adding custom data as part of VM update is not supported by the compute service, hence this option is not exposed in fluent VM update flow. An attempt to change custom data through VM update will cause below error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "PropertyChangeNotAllowed",
    "target": "customData",
    "message": "Changing property 'customData' is not allowed."
  }
}
```